# d3d11: Не найден указанный модуль. DirectPython 11

Tags: python, directx, модули, python-import, directx-11

Хотелось познакомиться с работой DirectPython 11. Скачал с офф сайта, поставил 32 битный Python, установил DirectPython 11 как предлагалось в начале установки в \Python39-32\Lib\site-packages. Открыл примеры и получаю ошибку

Система:
[image: система]
Версия Python:
[image: Версия Python]
установленные пакеты вижиалов:
[image: установленные пакеты вижиалов]
Путь установки DirectPython 11 и его файлов:
[image: Путь установки DirectPython 11 и его файлов]
Наличие d3d11.dll в системе:
[image: Наличие d3d11.dll в системе]
Ошибка:
[image: Ошибка]

Код примера Tutorial1.py

```
#Import DirectPython modules and constants.
import d3d11
from d3d11c import *

#First we need a window. If you don't want to do any visible
#rendering this could be omitted.
window = d3d11.Window()
window.setTitle("Tutorial 1 - Black window")
window.show(SW_SHOW)

#Then create a Device and tell it to use our window for drawing.
#Use a software WARP-device, in real applications you might
#try hardware first and fall back to software if that fails.
device = d3d11.Device(window, DRIVER_TYPE_WARP)

def mainloop():
    while 1:
        #Check all new messages.
        for msg in window.getMessages():
            if msg.code == WM_DESTROY:
                #Close the application. After you have received
                #this message don't try to use the window,
                #it has been destroyed.
                return
         
        #Set default render targets. This also clears the
        #render target to black and depth stencil buffer to 1.0
        device.setRenderTargetsDefault()
    
        #Present our rendering to the window. Because nothing 
        #has been drawn you will see a black window.
        #The argument '1'-tells the device to wait for 1
        #vertical syncronization before presenting.
        device.present(1)
        
#Start the mainloop.            
mainloop()
```

Не могу разобраться почему ошибка.

dependency walker:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
текст ошибки:

> Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
> Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
> Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
> Error: A circular dependency was detected.
> Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
> Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

тот самый d3d11.dll который отсутствует так же в модулях не отобразился
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это получается все API недоступны? и проект не запустится ? И сделать ничего нельзя?

Comment: Вам стоит взять dependency walker и пройтись по зависимостям динамических библиотек, начиная с .pyd А вообще этот проект выглядит полностью заброшенным.

Comment: @user7860670 попробовал, вылезли куча файлов которые неудается найти, все начинаются с API, добавил это в пост выше

Comment: После установки перезапускали IDE?

Comment: @gil9red, после установки Python имеете ввиду? Да, конечно и путь к нему указал.

Comment: API-* есть в системе, видимо этот вариант dependency walker их не обнаруживает. А вот python26.dll нет - это важно.

Comment: @user7860670 dependency walker скачан последней версии с официального сайта. Этот python26.dll можно скачать отдельно или он с python 2 идет комплектом ? python так же с официального сайта скачивался. Последнюю версию, но х86

Comment: без понятия, откуда, но по логике наверное с python 2.6 должна идти